# Loading MongoDB dump (*.bson.gz) file using Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, bson, mongodump

I am getting snapshot of Mango DB with **bson.gz** extension in a s3 location.
I am trying to read and load the file using pyspark, but it is giving me error. I am
using Jupyter notebook for this activity. Has anyone handled anything like this ? Please suggest.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
sc.install_pypi_package("pymongo==3.2.2")

import pymongo_spark
pymongo_spark.activate()
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("pyspark-bson")
file_path = "s3://location/users.bson.gz"
bsonFileRdd = sc.BSONFileRDD(file_path)
bsonFileRdd.take(5)
```

## Error

An error was encountered:
No module named 'pymongo_spark'
Traceback (most recent call last):
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymongo_spark'

Comment: Pls update your post with the error.

Comment: @Rm4n.. currently I am facing the above error. However I am also looking for a working code snippet for solving this problem . Thank You in advance.

Comment: When you print `sc.list_packages()`, do you actually see that `pymongo_spark` is indeed installed?